# How to type an object where both properties and values are from other types

Tags: typescript

I want to type an object where the property values are arrays that are only allowed to be a certain type and who's properties are also only allowed to be a certain type (a union type).  I tried two different ways below.  One with Record, which doesn't allow me to distinguish between the veg and fruit types.  And Interface which doesn't allow me to restrict the property name to being from a certain type.

[img of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OEyT.png)

```
type Veg = 'corn' | 'broccoli' | 'onion' | 'pumpkin' | 'squash' | 'kale';
type Fruit = 'banana' | 'apple' | 'orange' | 'pineapple' | 'passionfruit';
type AllowedFood =  Veg | Fruit;
type AllowedFoodGroups = 'veg' | 'fruit';

// allows me to put the wrong food type (a fruit) in veg (the orange)
const DietShoppingList: Record<AllowedFoodGroups, AllowedFood[]> = {
    veg: ['corn', 'onion', 'orange'],
    fruit: ['banana']
}


interface DietShoppingList2{
    veg: Veg[],
    fruit: Fruit[]
}


// correctly identifies that orange doesn't belong to veg but lets meat exist or any other food
const DietShoppingList2: DietShoppingList2 = {
    veg: ['corn', 'onion', 'orange'],
    fruit: ['banana'],
    meat: ['fish']
}
```

Comment: I don't get it... if you fix the `"orange"` error then [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) will catch the `meat` problem.  If the issue is that both errors don't show up *at once*, that's probably a design limitation since excess property checking probably happens only after other checks pass

Comment: See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAahDmUC8UDkBjA9gJwHaqgB80AjbTdLAGwEsDjVNcan60wBXAWzAGsb8RNAGcAjhwCGwgBZtUvCVQioA3AChQkKADFsHGsGSkJuExLkSwYJXJwn4yoajACIl644ZgpwlrgBmegaqamoCwBDY-hLo0AAiAMoAMlAA3mpQmVAAbggAXLAIANoAugA0GVmB+sAFujWlagC+oVi4woaJSQVdRulZOflQRRg4+GVoTH6o5ZWZ1QYFIyRmpjMVA1xutcOo-jQyM81AA).  Is that not sufficient?

Comment: @jcalz I guess I thought it would be cool if in the interface I was only allowed to have properties that existed in the AllowedFoodGroups list.  Whereas I could add "meat" to the interface and then there wouldn't be an error.

Comment: I don't understand; see the link in my previous comment.  That gives an error on `meat` as you want, right? (`Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'meat' does not exist in type 'DietShoppingList2'`)  What, specifically, do you want to see different?  Depending on your use case (and we'd need a different [mcve] for that I imagine) you might be looking for a workaround for the lack of [exact types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) in the language.  But excess property checks might be sufficient; I can't tell from your code.  Good luck!

Comment: [Relevant comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16076#issuecomment-514039387) in GitHub about excess property checks not warning if there are already errors in the same object.

Comment: Yes, I see that error, but someone could accidentally add meat to the interface DSL you created.  I want them to only be able to add properties to the interface that exist in the AllowedFoodGroups.

Comment: I'm confused; how could someone "accidentally" extend an interface definition?  The "someone" in this case is someone creating an interface?

Comment: Yea.. perhaps I'm overthinking it.  With the Record example, you can't add a property that didn't exist from the AllowedFoodGroups.  I thought it'd be cool to keep that restraint.

Comment: But with the `Record` example, someone can "accidentally" add `| "meat"` into `type DietShoppingList = Record<AllowedFoodGroups | "meat", AllowedFood[]>`. There are ways to make library typings harder for people to modify, but there's nothing that really prevents it entirely.

Comment: yea you are right.. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I took a shot at this [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAahDmUC8UDkBjA9gJwHaqgB80AjbTdLAGwEsDjVNcan60wBXAWzAGsb8RNAGcAjhwCGwgBZtUvCVQioA3AChQkKADFsHGsGSkJuExLkSwYJXJwn4yoajACIl644ZgpwlrgBmegaqGuDQAIJUVJgA7hAAJtqYmPFGsAhCuvrA6poRUbEJSSkA4uQcYMJGqABuCHKB2SFqAPQtUNgQwsDYNOjAVbwQIFXAmFCR0XGJyfFlmBXCADRQJByGilRQNYocXVASnVCY-lDCElzQeRMF08XxANoAuqFaACI0EMAAytKYVgJ4AAZGjdIwAJQgWGw8QAPJNCjNSuVKisEXdZs8AHxqVrtTaxKqXKBjKCcQzAaTQGLkXCIfyzElhKAACgkUEaBgAlFABNsMizKdA7HSIFy1FhcGD4p8fn8AXSQd0AFxQD5fX7-FyK0GGFAAbzUUGN-PgqoeGBw+BWjGYrBtIocqCeSyNJs5wHNqBIZlMztdJqglwknqgFv8oNkLwAvri2gdblUZf5-BBOrhDDsqHtlqt1lAhiMDunUIZOt1ev0EiTxuz4DQ6rgmZA1AJgGn-BJ0NB1XKtYClcAAExQQ2Bupm9LwZ4B91BUNZAzPNSxvEJqZEq7jckkqlQGlMemM65sjnznl8iesoXHbD2MUSpjS2WahXA3VD1W91-a99gg1usaE5etC1poEwfioA6d6iv6gFntkXo+qYfouvBwahuGkbOiucbtOWPR9AMBbDKM4zokUszzIsUAAGTroSUDJqm6aZrsXQrGshi4JgZYQBw5wkEorw9i+8q-oOADMyBuvR+phoWqoVoCTyqrgEB1NgUCxsackKcMancCQaaqVA6madpsmjvpIC8k2FFInMKLCKZ37iQOH4PIWTyWWu0KdP0VC2TQ8QQBmNARvslIhre95MZgXT4IYxnRHSNamnR8WJaWUBKIYGEHLgtm8VSWkMikUAQAAHrqUCPlKhgyhq7k6t0klfmJ-atcA0kAeOCAgVaUHgXaYGMDBTpoYGHpIb65hTSaGFehGMhwYGnBUMIXRevw8TqbZxkmMNqC0Fw7KHWNSjhVQOGrvGBGVsRhZkTcUyUciCyogxMRJhFLFhWx2YcYVqSgh0-GCcJ1wACoAEJvLCADSKzQ1iMm6dZXkGWchF0qZ5lppZGPyVjICGVwxnYPjGmEzpmUk4WdlQIjmWFicUDQ6Z0Okz5d3tP5ULAEFvKheFkWjNIMWOtA8QJcISWrBAqWIKSV70bL2WGHlQZuBsRXHEKZWMtVtX1c+zVdX+wAACyqnDCMOfc1FfW5luDkOaN9SawFhpaeDHRB9rgRNygLcaM2+8hZhrYtuvLdhYdkhwm3bb7u37YrR02qd51uJdAM0DdMZ4XmhepIEmBcJVNXdICdnttgnbdn5OABULwWi8AEWfBLUsh1l8s5Slh7pWrA8K9rBUmMVhscsbNeGGbjWdW+g4AKx2-D8K3O9Tmfbmrurx+nujvBPsWqBAejQHIcx+H86zSh82zsaS2+ytUYv0nKfCDtIUZxdY6OdM752urdEuawy5nkrnZWg6ljgkAAFaCxbtgNuwsQoF3FruPucUNaD2SkrEeqsMjqzlhPL4OsYrTwNqVOeFUTZgiXkxFeEldQADZN4Ox3o5Z2uYxzewGlOGc8EI6LmAMuaMJ8BFASERfIaDpr7QXvHfBCBhH7R0Tm-LCq1E4bS2r-NO-9hggKATQM6pjs4FyLiuIAA). Take a look at let me know what you think.

```js
type TBD<K, T> =
  & { [key: string]: never }
  & { [key: number]: never }
  & { [key in K & keyof T]: T[key] }

// correctly identifies that orange doesn't belong to veg & doesn't let meat any other food exist 
const dietShoppingList4: TBD<AllowedFoodGroups, DietShoppingList2> = {
    veg: ['corn', 'onion', 'orange'],
    fruit: ['banana'],
    meat: ['fish'],
    pulses: ['kidney bean', 'lima bean', 'lentil']
}
```

It doesn't give the same errors as when using a `Record` (i.e. `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'meat' does not exist in type 'Record<AllowedFoodGroups, AllowedFood[]>'`) but it does satisfy the goals of restricting both the keys & values while keeping keys to one type and allowing different value types.

I'm still rather new to TypeScript and types so perhaps there's another way to do this which would give better errors about invalid keys.